# Java - Get the array position from a method's parameter

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, position

```
void someMethod(int x){
    --do some calculations here--
}

...

int[]   i   = new int[8];
someMethod(i[3]);
```

Let's say in my *someMethod* I want to do calculations with the input parameter's value, which is the *i[3]*, and in my calculations also use the **position** of the original array, not only its value.

How do I tell within the method if the input parameter came from an array, and if it was an array, the position of the value that was used?

Something like this:

```
void someMethod(int x){

int y = 5;
int z = 0;
z = x + y + x.ArrayPosition;
System.out.print(z);

}
```

Comment: Without some black magic, this is not possible. The method never sees the array, only a value. This sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us why you need this information?

Comment: I have an ImageView[] array, and I added MouseEvent to them all, so when I click on of the pictures, it changes color etc. In this event (or rather method that contains this event) I need to define which ImageView was called to change its color

Comment: Either pass the `ImageView[]` as argument to the method or make it so that the surround class cann access the `ImageView[]`.

Comment: I passed ImageView[] as an argument to the method before, but let's say I have 16 images, and when one is clicked I want it to change color to Color.X and the other 15 to change color to Color.Y, like a radio button sort of. In this scenario I have to pass all the 16 ImageViews, so I will use an array as a parameter, but the method has to know which ImageView was clicked and that's why it would be important to know the position of the array

Comment: Second parameter: index of the clicked image.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just pass the array and the index as the function params ?

```
void someMethod(int[] array, int index) {
int y = 5, z = array[index] + y + index;
System.out.println(z); }
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: I see thank you, that solves the problem, I'm interested if there's a way to do it within the method without another parameter, if there's any built-in function that could be used

Comment: Sorry, I figured out I cannot do that either for this problem

Comment: I mean it is useful and helped me, thank you, I just added not for this problem which is my fault for not defying it better and not knowing it better